# Cant understand output format using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization

I wrote the following code using `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
class ClassToTestOutputStream implements Serializable{

    int a;
    String b;

    public ClassToTestOutputStream(){
        a=10;
        b="Deepak";
    }

    public String toString() {

        String s = ""+a+" "+b;
        return s;
    }
}
public class UsingOutputStreams {

    ClassToTestOutputStream ref;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;

    public UsingOutputStreams(){
    try {
         oos = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ref = new ClassToTestOutputStream();
}

public void writeOnScreen(){

    try {
        System.out.println("Writing on Screen");
        oos.writeObject(ref);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UsingOutputStreams obj = new UsingOutputStreams();
        obj.writeOnScreen();
    } 
}
```

And I got answer :

> �� Writing on Screen
>
> sr ClassToTestOutputStream����S��M I aL bt Ljava/lang/String;xp
> t Deepak

Please help me figure out why such output gets printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` writes Java objects in a form that can be read by `ObjectInputStream`. The output produced is not intended for human consumption and contains metadata and values in binary form.  It is not meant to be human-readable.   Attempting to print or display data written to `ObjectOutputStream` will result in garbage, as you have seen.

You should carefully read the Javadoc for `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: Can u please, suggest what that metadata and binary values are, and why they are used.

Comment: @DeepakAhire The protocol is defined in the Java Object Serialization Specification, and that is where you should look. Not here.